# Alternative to Bloomberg Excel Add-In for EOD Stock Prices

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, bloomberg

Is there a more cost-effective alternative to Bloomberg Excel Add-In? 90% of the time I only use Bloomberg to download security (hundreds of U.S. and international stocks) historical price data. The formula I use is `=BDH(security, field,start date [mm/dd/yyyy], end date [mm/dd/yyyy], optional arguments)`.

I did some research online and found a few platforms like Factset. They provide analytical solutions which are more than what I needed. I am simply looking for alternative Excel Add-Ins to Bloomberg's or R packages that can download historical price data. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quandl - you can use Excel, R python addin/code to pull data

Comment: I also found and got in touch with Quandl. It looks promising!

Answer (score 2):

I also heavily rely on Bloomberg for price data at work.  For single stock price history I leveraged **Yahoo Finance** in the past.  The quantmod() R package has some functions that can pull Yahoo Finance equity quotes.  I'm sure there are others, too.  I would try that route first.

Answer (score 1):

[Money.net](https://www.money.net/) also provides an Excel add-in (details see [here](https://moneynet.atlassian.net/wiki/display/reference/Excel+Add-in+User+Guide)).

Answer (score 1):

I've built an Excel Add-in (https://www.excelpricefeed.com/) which enables retrieval of data from Yahoo Finance (as well as other data providers). The Add-in currently provides live and historic prices to Excel cells via simple formulas such as:

```
=EPF.Yahoo.Price("AAPL")

=EPF.Yahoo.Historic.Close("TSLA", "1 May 2019")
```

It also has a UI for bulk downloading historic data to Excel.

Hope you find it useful.